Connecting to Spanner with DBeaver
I can connect using a key generated from a service account but I don't have the option to connect with IAM using my own google account.
The documentation shows this screenshot:

The problem is my authentication section only has the option to set the path to the private key. I don't have the "Authentication" and "Credentials" sections.

I'm using version 24.2.2 on dbeaver and 2.23.0 for the spanner driver.

I had already tried the default credentials. That didn't work.
The fix is to use a paid version of DBeaver. The community version only has the private key option.


Make sure that you have set your user credentials as the default application credentials.
Leave the private key path field empty. The will instruct the Spanner JDBC driver to use the default credentials of the environment.
Create the connection.

